# NSURLConnection returns NSError with only english as language?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

If i turn on Airplane mode on my iPad and trying to make a NSURLConnection i will get an error "The Internet connection appears to be offline." If i change to any other language then english on my iPad i will still have the same error text. Shouldn't i get the error in the current language that is choosen?

Using this code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: It depends if the localized description is actually supplied. If there is no localized description, the error description will default to a fallback language, most likely English.

Comment: Also, is your app localized in the other language? If not, the OS won't use its localized strings.

Comment: Thanks Ole, problem was that i had only english as localized language in my app becouse of development.

Comment: I'm doing something similar: I want to show a custom message for each `[error localizedDescription];` but I can't find the list or I don't know how to do this. I've googled a lot and have read most of the stackoverflow questions, but I couldn't find a clear answer to this question. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my question, and since it's related to this question, I'm sharing it so that it can help if someone else needs it.

The file containing error codes and localized descriptions, is located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.Framework/Resources/en.lproj/FoundationErrors.strings`
Copy this file and paste somewhere else (to avoid messing up with the original file). Now run the command in terminal to convert the binary file to a text file:
`plutil -convert xml1 FoundationErrors.strings`
Now drag the file into your Xcode project and right click and select `Open as... Property list`. Now you have the keys and the descriptions. You can translate (if your desired language isn't available in localization) or customize them as you want, and save it with a desired name which is `Persian.strings` in my case.

Now add this code to the method where you want to use it:

```
//persian error messages file full path
NSString * persianErrorsListFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Persian.strings"];
//Load file as dictionary
NSDictionary * persianErrorsList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:persianErrorsListFile];

NSString *errorKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Err%ld", (long)errorCode];
NSString *errorMessage = persianErrorsList[errorKey];
```

Comment: I just tried this method, but getting an error : -bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.Framework/Resources/en.lproj/FoundationErrors.strings: Permission denied

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S At which stage do you get this error? Did you copy that file and paste it into another readable & writable directory?

Comment: Yes, I copied that file in my desktop and also gave read & wite access.But showing the same error "Permission denied"

Comment: Could you give some more detail on where and when you get this error?

Comment: I just copied the FoundationErr‌​ors.strings files into a new folder in my desktop. In the GetInfo I changed the permission of the file to read & write. Now I opened the terminal and tried cd <path to the folder>. Next I tried plutil -convert xml1 FoundationErrors.strings. In this time I got an error "Permission denied". Is there any mistakes in these steps ?

Comment: No, no mistakes as far as I can see. I just tried doing this myself again, to make sure it works, and it actually does. I don't get an error there. Also I don't change the permissions, just paste it to desktop, and keep the permissions as is: http://cl.ly/image/2V1S1J0e0Y3r/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-08%20at%208.06.05%20PM.png

Comment: Ok @VishnuKumar.S. Try using the following command instead of the first one and see if you get the same error or not:
`plutil -convert xml1 FoundationErrors.strings -o /tmp/TextFoundationErrors.xml`

If it works, the text xml file will be in `/tmp/` folder.