# How to get Localized NSError

Tags: ios, localization, nserror

I have done a lot of google search without success. 
I would like to use the system localization of NSError (In my case in french)

I have try many things but the wording are always in english.

The configuration off my app :

**In the plist :** 
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion = fr_FR

**In the pbxproj:** 
developmentRegion = fr;
knownRegions = (
    fr,
    Base,
);

When I call the property "localizedDescription" I always get english version like this link ([NSError localizedDescription always returns english error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733837/nserror-localizeddescription-always-returns-english-error-message)) but the solution doesn't work for me...

I don't found what I'm missing.

In this other link [NSURLConnection returns NSError with only english as language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050125/nsurlconnection-returns-nserror-with-only-english-as-language) they copy the strings but I don't think it's the better way, we should be able to access the file without copy it.

For information when I use an UIBarButtonItem like Cancel, it's localized in french.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a localisation file with key and value strings.
Now when you want to show the localisation error, you can use following method

NSLocalizedString(<#key#>, <#comment#>)

Comment: This is not my problem, I want to use the native localized strings given by apple. The localizedDescription should do the trick but I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue the solution was to set the **info.plist** attribute **Localization native development region** to your region: **France** in this case